# Python Pandas replace sub-string in column with sub-string in another column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, str-replace

I have a Python Pandas data frame like following:

```
Id      Title            URL                                       PosterPath
Id-1    Bruce Almighty   https://www.youtube.com/embed/5VGyTOGxyVA  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XXXRRR/hqdefault.jpg
Id-2    Superhero Movie  https://www.youtube.com/embed/3BnXz-7-y-o  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XXXRRR/hqdefault.jpg
Id-3    Taken            https://www.youtube.com/embed/vjbfiOERDYs  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XXXRRR/hqdefault.jpg
```

I want to replace sub-string "XXXRRR" from column PosterPath with sub-string which comes after the string "embed/" from the column "URL"
Output data frame would look like following:

```
Id      Title            URL                                       PosterPath
Id-1    Bruce Almighty   https://www.youtube.com/embed/5VGyTOGxyVA  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5VGyTOGxyVA/hqdefault.jpg
Id-2    Superhero Movie  https://www.youtube.com/embed/3BnXz-7-y-o  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3BnXz-7-y-o/hqdefault.jpg
Id-3    Taken            https://www.youtube.com/embed/vjbfiOERDYs  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vjbfiOERDYs/hqdefault.jpg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
a = df['URL'].str.extract('embed/(.*)$', expand=False)
print (a)
0    5VGyTOGxyVA
1    3BnXz-7-y-o
2    vjbfiOERDYs
Name: URL, dtype: object

df['PosterPath'] = df['PosterPath'].replace('XXXRRR', a, regex=True)
print (df)
     Id            Title                                        URL  \
0  Id-1   Bruce Almighty  https://www.youtube.com/embed/5VGyTOGxyVA   
1  Id-2  Superhero Movie  https://www.youtube.com/embed/3BnXz-7-y-o   
2  Id-3            Taken  https://www.youtube.com/embed/vjbfiOERDYs   

                                         PosterPath  
0  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5VGyTOGxyVA/hqdefault.jpg  
1  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3BnXz-7-y-o/hqdefault.jpg  
2  https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vjbfiOERDYs/hqdefault.jpg
```

Comment: Awesome answer!!